# Homeomorphism of the real line-Topology

Tags: general-topology

I need to show that any open interval is homeomorphic to the real line.

I know that $f(x)=a+e^x$ will work for the mapping $f:R \to (a,\infty)$ and $f(x)=b-e^{-x}$ will work for the mapping $f:R \to (-\infty,b).$

Without using two functions, how can I prove the result in general?

Comment: Why not use these two functions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've already been given two possible homeomorphisms, but how about another one?

Say that you have two maps $\varphi : A \to B$ and $\psi : B \to C$, both of which are homeomorphisms.  It's clear that $\psi \circ \varphi : A \to C$ is again a homeomorphism.

Using this fact, choose your favorite finite open interval $(a,b)$, and prove it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Next up, take an arbitrary open interval $(c,d)$, and construct a homeomorphism between this an $(a,b)$, and voila, you are done.

In particular, look at the interval $(0,1)$, and its image under the function $\tan(\pi(x-\frac{1}{2}))$.  This is pretty clearly a homeomorphism.  Now just map an open interval to $(0,1)$ (homeomorphically), and call it a day.

Answer (score 20):

Let
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2-1}.
$$
This is a homeomorphism from $(-1,1)$ to $\mathbb R$.

Let
$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{1+2^{-x}}.
$$
That is a homeopmorphism from $\mathbb R$ to $(0,1)$.

For any other bounded interval $(a,b)$, just rescale and relocate.

Comment: To show that the real line is homeomorphic to any inteval,I need to show that (0,1) is homeomorphic to R and any two intervals are homeomorphic.so that  I can find a composition function then that is a homeomorphism.So can you please help me with this idea?

Comment: @ccc : Let $\ell(x)=a(1-x)+bx$.  Then $\ell$ is a homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ to $(a,b)$.  (That is what I meant by "rescale and relocate".)  Thus every open interval is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$.  And since the function $g$ in the answer is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R$ to $(0,1)$, the composition gives a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R$ to $(a,b)$.

Comment: thanks Michael,I understand the method,but do I need to define a function for the composition,i.e  from R to (a,b)?

Comment: You have $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+2^{-x}}$ going from $\mathbb R$ to $(0,1)$ and $\ell(x)=a(1-x)+bx$ going from $(0,1)$ to $(a,b)$, so $\ell(g(x)) = a\left(1-\dfrac{1}{1+2^{-x}}\right)+b\left(\dfrac{1}{1+2^{-x}}\right)$ goes from $\mathbb R$ to $(a,b)$.  With a bit of algebra you can simplify that last expression somewhat.

Comment: The first one is not even injective

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $\log(b-x)-\log(x-a)$

Comment: how can we show that the inverse is continuous here?

Comment: @ccc: Solving $y = \log(b-x) - \log(x-a)$ for x would work.