# Proof of topological isomorphism

Tags: general-topology

I remember reading in a section in plato.stanford.edu that the interval $(-∞, t)$ is topologically isomorphic to the interval $(0, t)$. I am not that good with topology, so could someone show me the proof, if this is true?

Comment: You need to establish a homeomorphism, i.e., find a continuous invertible map from $(0,t)$ to $(-\infty, t)$ with continuous inverse. Note that the $\tan(x)$ maps $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ to $(-\infty,\infty)$. Try modifying this function by scaling, shifting, and specifying its domain.

Answer (score 4):

A picture homeomorphism, updated with animation
[image]

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: Can you see it now?

Comment: I think so. A homeomorphism, if I'm correct, is a function that is bijective, continuos and also has a continuos inverse. It is bijective, since every u value makes exactly one fu (Im taking that as f(u) ) value, which corresponds to one point on the interval (0,t). You used e, so I hope I'm correct in assuming that's exp(x). If that's the case, then it is continuous as is its inverse.

Comment: Since you asked a specific function, I change the picture. It relates to the $\tan$ function.

Comment: Then, yes, this makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

If $t>0$, then you can try the function $\phi:(-\infty,t)\to(0,t)$, defined as $$\phi(x)\equiv t\exp(x-t)\quad\forall x\in(-\infty,t).$$

Show that

- $\phi$ maps to $(0,t)$, indeed;
- $\phi$ is bijective (hint: it's strictly increasing);
- $\phi$ is continuous;
- the inverse function $\phi^{-1}:(0,t)\to(-\infty,t)$ exists and is continuous.

You will then have established that $\phi$ is a [homeomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism#Definition) (“topological isomorphism,” if you will) between $(-\infty,t)$ and $(0,t)$.

Comment: Why is ln(x) preferred to 1/x to send 0 to $∞$? Is it because you only need to define the function 1 way (with the knowledge that it is invertible) and that exp is continuous without exception, making the proof easier.

Comment: I have no general preference, just thought about the exponential function first. A suitably translated and dilated reciprocal function would work perfectly fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know topology, but I'm guessing that continuous real open intervals are homeomorphic if they are transformed by continuous, invertible functions over the domain [and that the inverse is continuous - thanks triple sec]. Is that right?

Some ideas here:

[Homeomorphism of the real line-Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242873/homeomorphism-of-the-real-line-topology)

Here is my guess:

(0,t) f(x) = x/t => (0,1)

(0,1) f(x) = 1/x => ($∞$, 1) (1/x is continuous over that domain)

($∞$, 1) f(x) = -x => ($-∞$, -1)

($-∞$, 1) f(x) = x + t + 1 => ($-∞$, t)

Comment: You also need to require that the inverse function be continuous.