# Prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ and that $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $(0, ∞)$. also is $\mathbb{R}$ isometric to $(0,1)$? to $(0,∞)$ ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242873/homeomorphism-of-the-real-line-topology

Comment: I just don't know how to approach when proving homeomorphisms

Comment: You start by finding a nice bijection. Then you prove that it is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

verify that $\tan ((2x-1) \frac {\pi} 2)$ is a homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ onto $\mathbb R$.