# Given a metric, find continuous map that maps to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: metric-spaces

I wanted to know how to approach the question of:

Given a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ does a continuous map $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ with the following property:

$$f([0,1]\times[0,1]) = \mathbb{R}^2 $$

exist ?

I currently am a little clueless on how to think about it. I would guess we can work with the map of $f^{-1}$ on our map. But again not really sure. A little pointer in the right direction might do the trick though.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, are you asking about the Euclidean metric or are you allowed to choose the metric as well? You only say "a metric".

Comment: It can be any metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such a function cannot exist. Continuous image of a compact set is a compact set, but $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not compact.

Comment: This answer is correct for the Euclidean topology, but as pointed out in the comments OP is allowing any metric.

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: and you already pointed out the example with the discrete metric. nice

Comment: @Mark Lauer This asnwer is correct. The question asks if $f$ exist for **every** metric and here is a metric for which there is no $f$.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the discrete one: $d(x, y) = 1$ if $x \neq y$ and $d(x, y) = 0$ if $x = y$. The discrete metric induces the discrete topology, i.e. every subset is open. To see this, observe that the ball of radius $1/2$ centered at a point $x$ is precisely the singleton $\{x\}$. Every function out of a discrete space is continuous, since every subset is open. Thus, you need only find a function with $f[[0, 1] \times [0, 1]] = \mathbb R^2$. I'd rather not write one down explicitly, but however you have proven that these sets have the same cardinality will produce such a function. If you're unfamiliar with why these sets have the same cardinality, here are some relevant links:

[bijection between open and closed intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28568/bijection-between-an-open-and-a-closed-interval)

[bijection between open interval and \mathbb R](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242873/homeomorphism-of-the-real-line-topology)

You can combine these to get a bijection $f: [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \longrightarrow \mathbb R^2$ which is then continuous in the discrete topology.

Comment: The way I read the question OP is asking if such a function exists for every metric. You cannot choose your metric.